# Как обновить переменную в C++

Tags: c++

Вот допустим у меня есть переменная `a` типа `int`, к ней прибавляются числа, и как сделать так что бы новое значение `a`, появлялось на месте старого?

Comment: Оно и так появляется на месте старого. Ваша переменная - несколько байт в памяти или значение в регистре. Прибавление числа меняет содержимое памяти/регистра.

Comment: Человек не в курсе про присваивание?

Answer (score 10):

Значение сразу появляется, если этого не произошло — Вы где-то ошиблись.

---

Если вы добавили числа вот так:

```
a = 1;
a = a + 2;
```

Результат сразу присваивается переменной а (и а будет иметь значение 3). Как написал Владимир ниже: — "Ваша переменная - несколько байт в памяти или значение в регистре. Прибавление числа меняет содержимое памяти/регистра".

Comment: ну с точки зрения С/С++  в аккурат пишется a += 2;

Comment: @maint, и не только С. Спрашивает новичок, ему это еще непонятно.